# WebBrowser and OLECMDID_SELECTALL

Tags: delphi, cursor, twebbrowser, selectall

When I open the Google web page using:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://www.google.com.au/advanced_search?hl=en');
```

it opens with the cursor in the edit box.
So when I use:

```
WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID_SELECTALL,OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER,vaIn, vaOut);
```

it only copies where the cursor is. Not the whole web page, which is what I want to copy. 
my code is:

```
procedure Pause()
begin
//code to pause until page loads.
end;

procedure TForm2.Button22Click(Sender: TObject);
var s:String;
    vaIn, vaOut: OleVariant;
begin
    s:='http://www.google.com.au/advanced_search?hl=en';
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(s);
    while WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
      begin
          Pause(1000);
      end;
//------->I need to put code here so the SELECTALL line of code works.<----------
//------->So the cursor isn't in to editbox but as if it has clicked  <---------- 
//------->the webpage                                                 <----------
    WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID_SELECTALL,OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER,vaIn, vaOut);
end;
```

How to select the whole web page?

Comment: Can u use TWebBrowser.Document.Copy ?
 http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.Document 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752116.aspx
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127.aspx

Comment: also look http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/7d19aa5c-5288-4176-8d3a-04ef44387c52 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/eef2f809-cadf-44a3-956e-e75925a4b85e

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? copy the content of that page or what?...

Comment: There's not even a question here...

Comment: Just trying to copy the text on the web page not the code that makes the web page. The code I'm using works if there are no edit boxes on the page. But if there is an edit box on the page and the cursor is in the edit box it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try focusing the body before selecting all:

```
((WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).body as IHTMLElement2).focus();
WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID_SELECTALL, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, vaIn, vaOut);
```

With that said a better approach would be to use `document.body.innerText` to grab the text, instead of simulating a select/copy like you do.

Comment: Kobik, you are a genius. And also funny. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the reminder. I pressed the up vote arrow. Thanks again. I only have 11 in the reputation ranking, so my up vote doesn't count, I need 15 before it will up vote.

Answer (score 1):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/eef2f809-cadf-44a3-956e-e75925a4b85e
 suggests explicit way to select all before copying. That way directly works only when page has no frames (Google Advanced has IFRAMEs and IHTMLBodyElement.CreateTextRange fails)

But the late-binding code to be like that works in XE2/Win7x64/IE9:

```
procedure TForm2.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var HTML_Doc, oRange: OleVariant;
begin
  HTML_Doc := WebBrowser1.Document;
  oRange := HTML_Doc.body.createTextRange;
  oRange.select();

  WB_Copy(webbrowser1);
end;
```

WBCopy is taken from WBFunks unit http://codingrus.ru/readarticle.php?article_id=721 and boils down to ExecWB call with OLECMDID_COPY, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT parameters.

Comment: Hi Arioch, Thanks for the code, which I have just tried and it works. But it copies all the content of the page. I just wanted to copy the text the you can see on the screen, not the content of the code of the page.

Comment: Hi TLama, the answer was given by kobik. Which is:((WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).body as IHTMLElement2).focus();
WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID_SELECTALL, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, vaIn, vaOut);

Comment: That depends how you paste. You can paste both HTML and plain text i believe. Try what got pasted into notepad. In more complex programs try Edit / paste special / format = plaintext

Comment: @james TLama refered to previous variant of answer, not to current